# How to efficiently byteswap binary data in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, binaryfiles, endianness

`byteswap` below does what I want, but I fear it is inefficient for larger chunks of binary data. Is there an efficient library function or something I can use?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString as B (ByteString, length, append, cons, foldl)

byteswap :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
byteswap = let
  swapper (collector, result) byte = let
    updated = B.cons byte collector
    in if 3 < B.length updated then ("", B.append result updated) else (updated, result)
  in snd . B.foldl swapper ("", "")

main = print $ byteswap "1234abcdXYZ"
```

Prints `4321dcba`.

Answer (score 2):

The slow part of your code is `append` which is linear in the size of the bytestring that you are generating, hence your program will take at least quadratic time.

Instead you can use a list as intermediate structure (which ideally would get fused away) and pack the whole result in one go:

```
byteswap :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
byteswap xs = B.pack
  [ B.index xs $ i * 4 + j
  | i <- [0 .. B.length xs `quot` 4 - 1]
  , j <- [3,2,1,0]
  ]
```

This can do 10 million bytes in 3 seconds on my machine.

You can speed it up by using unsafe internal bytestring functions:

```
byteswap :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
byteswap xs = unsafePackLenBytes (B.length xs `quot` 4 * 4)
  [ unsafeIndex xs $ i * 4 + j
  | i <- [0 .. B.length xs `quot` 4 - 1]
  , j <- [3,2,1,0]
  ]
```

And with [my patch for fusion of unsafePackLenBytes](https://github.com/haskell/bytestring/pull/494) I get 10 million bytes swapped in 6 ms.

Comment: Not sure I approve of writing this with `do` syntax instead of the obvious enough list comprehension...